# Can I stack functions on a variable?

Tags: php

Is there a problem with stacking functions on a variable. It seems to work but is there an underlying risk or problem doing this?

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['username']));
```

I don't really see a problem with it but I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm not sure if this would cause issues. As compared to:

```
$username = $strtolower($_POST['username']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
```

Just wondering if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. You could, of course, just run it to find out.

Comment: It's perfectly valid. Unless it impairs readability, it's actually preferred over temporary variables.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you notice, I know it works, I was asking if it's "okay" to do in terms of clean coding.

Comment: That completely depends on who you're asking and their style of coding. Note that this type of question would be classified as a *Close: Primarily opinion based* question, as well, if this is what you're asking.

Comment: the deeper you go the harder to debug

Comment: There is an underlying risk of mismatching parentheses.

Comment: @mario - Nah man, that is the *Bedknobs and Broomsticks* of adventure programming. `:P`

Comment: @mario Ah yeah, I knew that. I'm using PDO now anyway, but it was just an example. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem in nesting functions  like `mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($value))` as you propose. It can lead to easy to read and understand code. I would caution against going overboard with it, and nesting many many functions, however, as that quickly gets unreadable.

### But wait!!!

Do not be tempted to nest everything. Some functions require good error checking to be used effectively.  The `mysql_*()` functions related to querying and fetching in particular should *not* be nested ([actually they should not be used at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), use MySQLi or PDO instead).  It is pretty safe to nest string functions as you attempted, but always check the manual at http://php.net to make sure of the possible return types of the functions you are nesting. Be especially careful with functions [that return resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), such as those handling database connections, file handles, sockets, etc.

```
// Don't do this:
// mysqli_query() will return false on failure, which will 
// not be a valid argument to mysqli_fetch_array()
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl"));
```

If the query fails, it will result in a fatal error in your code since the object passed to the outermost function is not the type expected.

Instead, cases like this require error checking that make nesting impractical:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl");
if ($result) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

Another case to be wary of are functions [which expect references as their arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). For example, `array_merge()` returns an array but `sort()` expects a reference to an array (you wouldn't do this anyway since `sort()` doesn't return an array):

```
sort(array_merge([3,2,41], [5,1]));
// PHP Strict standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in php shell code on line 1
```

A related and more likely use case in practical terms would be passing a function return value into [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (which is technically a language construct rather than a function). Prior to PHP 5.5, only variables could be passed in, so the following would result in a parse error:

```
// Error in PHP < 5.5
if (empty(func_returning_string()) {}
```

Comment: Nothing the `@` operator won't fix. OF COURSE I KID.

Comment: Not a problem if you set *mysqli* to throw exceptions... `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)`

Comment: @Phil Sure - mysqli is the closest correlate example to the OP's, but this applies to many resource-returning things. I'll add a note.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, stack as many *function calls* as you like. Your example won't work however because you're missing a right paren